# Que faire des questions qui ne parlent pas du français ? What to do about questions that are not about French?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[À l'heure où j'écris](https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/859/4), [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/859/traduction-de-lexpression-doing-something-piecemeal-en-francais) ne parle pas de français. Elle demande, en français, l'explication d'une phrase en anglais. Si cette question était traduite en anglais, elle ne déparerait pas sur [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Le titre de la question est « Traduction de l'expression "Doing something piecemeal" en français ». Si le corps de la question était en conséquence, je n'aurais rien à redire. Mais rien dans le corps de la question ne parle de traduire, juste comprendre l'original anglais.

Que faire dans ce cas ?

- Éditer le corps de la question (donc en en changeant le sens) pour la faire rentrer d'une manière ou d'une autre dans le sujet du site. Ici, une possibilité claire est de demander une traduction française. C'est d'ailleurs ce que proposent toutes les réponses qui ont été proposées.
- Clore la question comme hors-sujet. Éventuellement éditer le titre pour le faire correspondre au corps. Si l'auteur édite ensuite sa question pour la faire rentrer dans le sujet du site, la rouvrir.
- La question étant presque appropriée pour le site [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), l'adapter (c'est-à-dire ici la traduire en anglais) et l'y migrer.
- Autre proposition ?

---

[As I write](https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/859/4), [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/859/traduction-de-lexpression-doing-something-piecemeal-en-francais) is not about French. It is asking, in French, for an explanation of an English sentence. If the question was translated into English, it would fit on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

The title of this question is “translating the expression ‘doing something piecemeal’ into French”. If the question body followed suit, I would have nothing against it. However nowhere in the question body is translation mentioned, the body clearly requests only an explanation of the English original.

What should we do?

- Edit the question body (thus changing its meaning) to make it fit into the topic of the site, one way or another. Here an obvious possibility is to request a French translation. All the existing answers provide a translation anyway.
- Close the question as off-topic. Possibly edit the title to make it match the body. Let the author edit the question if he wants, and reopen it if it's edited to be on-topic.
- Since the question is almost appropriate for English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), adapt it (which in this instance means translating the question into English) and migrate it there.
- Any other proposal?

Answer (score 4):

I think the question body isn't as far from the title as you say, so my vote would be to edit the body to match up better with the title, and hence become on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 4):

En général, l'usage est plutôt de s'arranger pour que le titre corresponde à la question que de modifier la question pour la faire correspondre au titre.  Le fait que le titre incite à penser que la question est en thème, tandis que le corps incite à penser l'inverse ne me semble pas être pertinent. Se poserait-on la question s'il s'agissait d'autre chose que d'une question qui peut à la limite être interprété comme une demande de traduction ?

En ce qui concerne ce genre question d'explication d'une expression anglaise. Il ne faut pas oublier que nous ne possédons une compétence en anglais que de manière accidentelle (tout comme collectivement nous avons vraisemblablement une bonne compétence sur des questions informatiques). Si le questionneur n'est pas là pour clarifier le sens de ce dont il demande un traduction, on pourrait très bien devoir poser la question sur EL&U avant de pouvoir en proposer une, ou devoir un proposer plusieurs de sens différent si l'expression est ambiguë.  Dans les autres questions demandant une traductions, le questionneur est là pour fournir les explications nécessaires, il peut clarifier le sens recherché, et dans les cas où la question est en français quelqu'un peut ne pas connaître l'anglais et proposer des réponses.  Ici ce n'est pas le cas, le questionneur est vraisemblablement capable lui-même de proposer des réponses une fois le sens connu (le fait est, il en propose deux et nous demande plus de choisir que de proposer d'autres alternatives avec comme critère de choix non la qualité du français mais le sens de l'expression en anglais).

Dans le cas particulier de la question et sa situation actuelle.  Vu que la formulation est déjà ambiguë (mais l'esprit pas) et que les réponses déjà apportées restent plutôt dans le thème, je n'ai pas d'objection à reformuler le corps plutôt que le titre.

Edit: Ce qui s'est passé pour l'[autre exemple](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/878/treize-quatorze-quinze-seize) donne une réponse partielle à ma question initiale. Et ce qui c'est passé me semble être un pratique acceptable. On ferme la question sauf si quelqu'un (OP ou autre) la reformule de manière plus acceptable et si ça se passe après la fermeture, on ré-ouvre.

---

Usually, the custom is to make the title fit the question instead of the reverse.  The fact that the title is on topic while the body isn't shouldn't be a factor.  I'm not sure we would wonder if the formulation of the question wasn't also border line between a translation question and an explanation one.

About explanation versus translation.  We shouldn't forget that we don't have a core competency in English due to the nature of the site but to the people who are on it (just as we probably have a good computer science knowledge). In another case, we could very well need to ask the question on EL&U before being able to propose any translation. In other translation question, the OP is there to clarify and paraphrase the idea he want to express (most already do without being asked); as a matter of fact if the question is in French someone who don't know English may propose a valid one, the English word is there only to make the question clearer.  Here the OP is probably able to propose a French way to express the idea, in fact he propose two and ask us to choose and the criteria we have to chose isn't the quality of the French, but the English meaning.

In the case of the linked question, considering that the formulation is already between asking a translation and asking an explanation (but the spirit is clear) and that questions are already on-topic, I've no objections on rewording the body so that it is more clearly on topic.

Edit: This [other exemple](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/878/treize-quatorze-quinze-seize) gives an answer to my opening question.  What occurred there is acceptable for me.  It was closed, someone (the OP or someone else) reformulated to center the question on a topical subject and then it was reopened.

Answer (score 3):

I think in cases like this, you can judge the question by its answers. The answers all seem to be 'on topic' for me. And though the *meaning* of the question might have its home on EL&U, the *expression* of it wouldn't, because it's in French.

If someone is trying to understand an English phrase 'in French', then that *is* implicitly translation (sort of), to my mind.

And if you think about it, even though 'officially' we don't do French to English translation here, if someone asks a question in English about the meaning of a French expression, then it's implicitly a translation question too.